# Python Logical Operators find the right way if(and and or or)

Tags: python-3.x

Can not find the mistake in logical operators, may be someone can give me a hint how to put AND OR OR.

Problem is with if data and data and data and (or or or)

in () > I need to accept code:
contains capital letters, then the number of capitals must be odd
have at least 4 letters (independent of case)
so it means: UPPER + LOWER >= 4 or UPPER >= 4 or LOWER >= 4

output should be:

```
checker_code("Dfgh#88$")
True
```

```
def checker_code(security_code):
    data = {'upper':0, 'lower':0, 'spec':0, 'digit':0, 'sum':0}
    spec_charact = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','?',',','.']
    if len(security_code) < 8 or len(security_code) > 30:
        return False
    for i in security_code:
        if any(i.isupper() for i in security_code):
            data['upper'] = data['upper'] + 1
        if i.islower():
            data['lower'] = data['lower'] + 1
        if i in spec_charact:
            data['spec'] = data['spec'] + 1
        if i.isdigit():
            data['digit'] = data['digit'] + 1
        if i.isdigit():
            data['sum'] = data['sum'] + int(i)   
    if(data['upper'] % 2 !=0 and data['spec'] >= 2 and data['digit'] >= 2 and data['sum'] % 2 == 0 and (data['upper'] + data['lower'] >= 4 or data['upper'] >= 4 or case['lower'] >= 4)):
        return True            
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: data['upper'] % 2 is returning 0 for your example test case, which immediately is violating your conditional

Comment: printing data['upper'] for your test case returned 8, the same length of your string. I put an answer explaining what's causing this and how to fix

Comment: Thank you. I think it was already too late) My initial code was if i.isupper(): ... but somehow I changed it and forgot. now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line

```
if any(i.isupper() for i in security_code):
```

to this:

```
if i.isupper():
```

Since you are already iterating `for i in security_code` in your outer for loop, it is redundant to do it again in your first if-statement. I think your code is applying whether the 1st character is upper across all letters, so it thinks your string of 8 characters has 8 upper-case characters since "D" is uppercase

Answer (score 1):

Your test `if any(i.isupper() for i in security_code):` is adding to `data["upper"]` everytime through the loop because you are checking all of `security_code` at every iteration and since it does have a uppercase letter, it adds to the count.

Instead, just do `if i.issuper():` to only check the current element of the security code.